# PHP Form with Multiple Dynamically Created Input Fields With Same Name

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I'm building a dynamic form that a user can create more Cards and within those cards they can create more child fields - Please see image for a demonstration.

Html Sample:

```
      <fieldset data-CardIndex="1">
        <div class="delete">X</div>
          <input type="text" name="firstField[]" value="" required>
          <input type="text" name="secondField[]" value="" required>
          <input type="text" name="thirdField[]" value="" required>
          <a class="addLinkBtn">+ Add More Child Fields</a>
          <div class="childWrapper">
             <input type="text" name="childOne[]" value="" required>
             <input type="text" name="childTwo[]" value="" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
```

When I submit the Form with three cards for example, in Card1 there is a set of childOne and childTwo, in Card2 there two sets, and in Card3 there is one set. I get the following array:

```
Array
(
   [firstField] => Array
   (
      [0] => a
      [1] => b
      [2] => c
   )
   [secondField] => Array
   (
      [0] => a
      [1] => b
      [2] => c
   )
   [thirdField] => Array
   (
      [0] => a
      [1] => b
      [2] => c
   )
   [childOne] => Array
   (
      [0] => aa
      [1] => bb
      [2] => bbbb
      [3] => cc
   )
   [childTwo] => Array
   (
      [0] => aa
      [1] => bb
      [2] => bbbb
      [3] => cc
   )
   [submit_update] => 
)
```

But I would like to receive something along these lines:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
   (
      [firstField] => a
      [secondField] => a
      [thirdField] => a
      [0] => Array
      (
         [childOne] => aa
         [childTwo] => aa
      )
   )
   [1] => Array
   (
      [firstField] => b
      [secondField] => b
      [thirdField] => b
      [0] => Array
      (
         [childOne] => bb
         [childTwo] => bb
      )
      [1] => Array
      (
         [childOne] => bbbb
         [childTwo] => bbbb
      )
   )
   [2] => Array
   (
      [firstField] => c
      [secondField] => c
      [thirdField] => c
      [0] => Array
      (
         [childOne] => cc
         [childTwo] => cc
      )
   )
   [submit_update] => 
)
```

Is there a way that I can build either the HTML or call a PHP function that would get me the output Im looking for?

The reason Im looking for this solution is because when you have a bunch of child sets it becomes a nightmare trying to figure out which set belongs in which card. I tried using unique identifying such as `name="childOne[1-1]"` representing it belongs in Card1 and is the first child set. Couldn't quite get it working this route either.

Any input you guys have is much appreciated, Ive been battling this on and off for a whole week.

Thanks

[image: example]

Comment: In your html if you want to create a multidimensional array replace `firstField[]` with `firstField[childfield[]]` and you can do the following `firstField[childfield][]`

Comment: Sorry, Im not understanding. Why would `firstField[childField[]]` do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Parent and child arrays are `multidimensional arrays` , so to achieve that with html you need to append array in array to create a child-parent array